# How do you pull multiple TFS repos into a single Jenkins job?

Tags: tfs, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a repo that has 2 subfolders $/Repo/project and $/Repo/thirdparty.  I need to pull both of those into Jenkins for a single build.  Naturally I tried just pulling $/Repo, but this gives me a bunch of other projects along with false polls (it will build every time ANYTHING is checked into $/Repo).  I have tried using the multi-scm plugin which works, but does not save the configuration (annoying, but not unusable). I tried using the regular tfs plugin and manually putting the calls for the other repo into a windows command (this did not work even through i bound them them to different folders).

What is the best way to approach this? Some sort of subjob that pulls third party? Fix the multiple scm plugin? Is there some tfs command or trigger to pull a different repo when you pull a project?

Comment: Are you using the same repository type for all projects? All from TFS?

Comment: Yes they are all part of the same repo.

Comment: Then you're... well... screwed. Two ways to go - either implement multi repo feature in TFS plugin (like SVN and git already have), or with with multi-scm-plugin - but it was designed with different purpose in mind. Anyway, no option for now.

Comment: do you think firing off a job to pull the thirdparty stuff (like a separate dependent job) or something would work out?

Comment: Yes, it might. It depends how your project is organized and what kind of files you're actually pulling out of TFS. Maybe creating a workspace with import definition would be sufficient AND the Jenkins plugin can understand those? - not sure by myself. And one other idea - check the answer.

Comment: Any idea why the plugin + manual calls didn't work?

Comment: Dave: Ya its the weird way tfs does the workspace.  I got strange results when trying to create 2 workspaces in the same folder, so i tried putting them in their own folders which i think is possible if you use the cmd line to do both clones, problem is I need polling on so if you don't configure the repository through the plugin polling won't work.  For now I am just pulling the parent of the 2 folders I need and putting up with the extra stuff.  My next idea to try is making a separate job that pulls our thirdparty stuff into a special location.  Ill tell you how that works out.

Comment: Just hit this issue.  In my version of the shared-parent "$/Repo/", I'd have to bring down the whole kitchen sink to build.  This stinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TFS pluging for Jenkins currently does not support checking out the sources from multiple locations. multiple-scm-plugin might be the answer, but as You pointed out in the question - it's really not an option at this point. There are really, as far I can see it, only to possible solutions for you to test out:

1. Create a workspace within TFS that will include all the neccesary imports. I use this functionality in my every-day encounters with TFS, although I have never a chance to use that with Jenkins plugin. It might work, it might not.
2. You can use, and please - this is a quite serious option, at least for me - git. There is a [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) and import all of the required projects into git repository. And having them in git will open a bunch of possibilities for you, including using separate repos for every folder, using git modules, git externals... and so on. So, at least for me, it is a valid option, although it seems like an ugly workaround at the first look...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We do use git here for some stuff, and I like it alot, but when it comes to the .NET developers they want to use tfs.  I will try some of the work arounds we discussed and see how that plays out.

Comment: Well, git-tfs will let them use TFS anyway, and Git will be only covered by Jenkins. And I do understand why they want to use TFS (mostly of tight integration with VS.Net), but on the build/archive/distribution side of the story Git is actually better suited for the job. I think you should give both a try and use the one that will suite **You** and **Jenkins** better, as none of them will interfere with VS.Net developers and TFS.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this working with a job pipeline.  It's kinda hacky, but it works.

The program I'm trying to build uses `$/Department/Framework/Main` (as `workspace\Framework`), and `$/Department/Products/TheProgram/Main` (as `workspace\TheProgram`).

I created three jobs in Jenkins, each "downstream" of the other:

- Framework-Get: normal source code triggering on TFS' Project Path of `$/Department/Framework/Main`.  No build step.
- TheProgram-Get: normal source code triggering on TFS' Product Path of `$/Department/Products/TheProgram`.  No build step.
- TheProgram-Build: No source code control.  But the build steps xcopy's the source from the above two steps.  Then, you can run a normal build step.

TheProgram-Build's first build step is a windows batch command:

```
REM ====================================
REM First Get the Framework folder:
rmdir /s/q Framework
mkdir Framework
xcopy /y /q /e ..\..\Framework-Get\Workspace\Framework Framework

REM ====================================
REM Then Get the TheProgram Folder:
rmdir /s/q TheProgram 
mkdir TheProgram 
xcopy /y /q /e ..\..\TheProgram-Get\Workspace\TheProgram TheProgram
```

The second build step was a simple call to ant.  But you could use msbuild or whatever you like here.

Answer (score 1):

The TFS plugin supports the ability to cloak folders in your `$\Repo` that you are not interested in.  Checkins to cloaked folders will not trigger a build.  Unfortunately that may be a lot of folders and you are only interested in two - you would need to maintain the list of cloaked folders as new ones are added.

We avoid the TFS plugin and instead scripted the setup of our TFS workspaces via powershell step using the tfs commandline.  Each build specifies the folders it wants and the script takes care to cloak/uncloak the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is to create two Jobs, one that just download your dependency and another to make the build.

In my case I managed the build with Maven properties, for example:

#### pom.xml

```
<properties>
  <my.dir>../MyDir</wsdl.dir>
</properties>
```

#### Jenkins Build

```
Goals clean package -U -Dmy.dir=${WORKSPACE}/../../another-build/workspace/MyDir
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a workaround myself for Jenkins. This was achieved using both TF and the powershell Snapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell.

Basically the workflow is as follows :

Get-TFsWorkspace (Powershell : To check for the workspace)

TF Workspace /new (To Create a workspace)

TF Workfold /unmap (use this to remove the default $/ mapping which is made during workspace creation)

TF Workfold /map (To map specific locations, ie $/Repo/project)

TF Scorch (to remove any artifacts if there are any)

TF Get (To get the code)

There may be other methods that people have, but this would allow you to use the tf Workfold /cloak functionality as well.

Cheers,

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm that that Multiple SCM 0.5 works with the Team Foundation Server plug-in 4.0

The polling does seem to break however.