# Let Jenkins build from multiple TFS repositories

Tags: jenkins, tfs, version-control, repository

I have a problem with Jenkins building my source code. I'm using a lib repo and a repo for my code. I want Jenkins to build the project if anything in one of the repos changes.

Does anyone has some pointer how to solve this? I managed to get it working in the case that everything is in only one repo, but I want to separate the lib and the project code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,the TFS pluging for Jenkins currently does not support checking out the sources from multiple locations.

However, as a work around you could use the ***command line*** to create any sort of workspace that you like, and even copy a template workspace that you have lying around.

To achieved this use both TF and the powershell Snapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell.

Basically the workflow is as follows :

> Get-TFsWorkspace (Powershell : To check for the workspace)
>
> TF Workspace /new (To Create a workspace)
>
> TF Workfold /unmap (use this to remove the default $/ mapping which is
>   made during workspace creation)
>
> TF Workfold /map (To map specific locations, ie $/Repo/project)
>
> TF Scorch (to remove any artifacts if there are any)
>
> TF Get (To get the code)

More details please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31349536/5391065) in a similar question.